# Apache - building extensions with apxs

Tags: apache-2.2, installation

Pardon the newbie question - I haven't worked with manually compiling Apache modules (or anything) before.  I am trying to get the mod_concat module going.  It seems simple enough - just requires downloading the mod_concat.c file and then running:

```
axps -c mod_concat.c
```

This is new to me. Does it matter which directory I put mod_concat.c before running this command?  I ran it from my home directory, and I see some new files - mod_concat.la, mod_concat.lo, mod_concat.o, and mod_concat.slo - along with a new subfolder called .libs/ that contains mod_concat.so along with some other files.

I'm not sure where to go from here, I have a feeling these files were created in the wrong place.  Don't I need mod_concat.so to be in my apache modules directory with the rest?

Thanks for the help, Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cp directorywhereitis/filethatyouwant /directorywhereitgoes
```

Comment: Is it just the mod_concat.so that needs to be copied into my Apache modules directory?  What about those other files and the .libs/ folder that was created?  Thanks.

Comment: They're just intermediate files that are used for building the shared object. `.libs/` is just a convenient place to stuff the shared object. Convenient for the build routine, that is.